# Como hacer un recorrido de N registros en Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo este código que me verifica si el numero id ingresado en un formulario existe en el registro:

```
callAjax("http://page.app/serial?" + Date["now"](), function (a) {
  console["log"]("resultcheck", a);
  try {
   a = JSON["parse"](a)
  } catch (e) {};
  g["freeBussy"] = false;
  // Aqui verrifico el id 
  if (b == a["id"]) {
   g["setstatus"](true, a["id"], f);
   return c(true)
  };
 g["setstatus"](false, null, f);
 return c(false)
}
```

El problema es que ahora quiero buscar y verificar el id en todos los registros de la base de datos.

Anteriormente mandaba un array de esta manera (Solo 1 registro):

```
{"id":2,"email":"user1@gmail.com","name":"User example 1","online":0}
```

Ahora estoy mandando de esta manera, es decir N registros.

```
[
  {"id":2,"email":"user3@gmail.com","name":"User example 3","c":false},
  {"id":2,"email":"user2@gmail.com","name":"User example 2","c":false},
  {"id":1,"email":"user1@gmail.com","name":"User Example 1","c":false}
]
```

Esto lo estoy mandando del controlador:

```
public function serial(Request $request){
    $users = User::select('id','email','name','online')->where('status','=','1')
                ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                ->get();

    return response()->json($users);
}
```

Pensé en un foreach, pero estuve buscando el google, y lastimosamente no encontré mucha información acerca de lo que quiero realizar.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach). te permite iterar y ejecutar una función por cada elemento de un Array.

Ejemplo:

```
callAjax("http://page.app/serial?" + Date["now"](), function (a) {
  console["log"]("resultcheck", a);
  try {
   a = JSON["parse"](a)
  } catch (err) {console.log(err)};
  g["freeBussy"] = false;
  // Aqui verrifico el id 
  a.forEach(function(a) {
   if (b == a["id"]) {
    g["setstatus"](true, a["id"], f);
    return c(true)
   };
  });
  g["setstatus"](false, null, f);
  return c(false)
}
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo. :)

Comment: Te cuento que no me funcionó... Es una extensión para google chrome, puedo pasarte para que me ayudes?

Comment: Jhosselin hubo un error lo correcto es `forEach()`, la e es en mayúscula.

Comment: Tampoco me funcionó, te puedo enviar la extensión?

Comment: ok envía la extensión.

Comment: Te envié un .rar dentro de ella hay una carpeta llamada "base" ahí dentro existe un archivo llamada brackground.js es ahí donde esta el código apartir de la linea 87. https://www.mediafire.com/?30ooqbo3qdoxz2v

Comment: Para instalar la extensión http://prntscr.com/fajb3z y luego selecciona la carpeta "base".

Comment: El otro programado hizo con un while, pero si abrimos la URL al cual hace el llamado esta es un formato normal. https://marzct.github.io/db/serial.js Ahora estamos apuntado hacia esta dirección https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0l2xf16u9pfenh3/serial.js

Comment: Y más abajo en la 114 llamamos de nuevo al https://marzct.github.io/db/serial.js? . Gracias.

Comment: Jhosselin estoy intentando hacer un seguimiento pero se desactiva la aplicación, deberás entregarme la ultima versión funcional y luego analizamos los cambios que quieres hacer, te parece?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59086/discussion-between-jhosselin-gimenez-and-fwbasic).